# Best HttpClient / ServicePointManager settings for performance?

Tags: performance, https, httpclient, servicepoint

I'm using **HttpClient** to make batches of request to a number of servers. There may be a number of batches in progress at any given time.

I use one  Httpclient per batch which will all go to the same server.
So if I have 3 jobs in flight to 3 servers I use one HttpClient per server.

A job makes **100 to 2000 requests** to the server endpoint and **3 to 5 request asysnc**.

The server endpoint config is beyond my control.

What I want to know what are the **best settings to ensure success and performance?**

So **for example** I already have a ServicePointManager.**ServerCertificateValidationCallback** that always returns true.
I set ServicePointManager.**DefaultConnectionLimit** to 100

I'm wondering what settings I need for things like 
ServicePointManager.**SecurityProtocol**
ServicePointManager.**SetTcpKeepAlive**
and **anything else?**

to **always ensure success** in particular around their HTTP/HTTPS setup and what tweaks might help with performance?